# No suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [CustomClass]

Tags: java, spring, response, resttemplate, spring-rest

There is a lot of questions like this, but nothing helps.
I am trying to get response from rest api like this:

```
private void createActorInstance(AbstractActorDTO actor)
    {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_NAME, BASIC_AUTHORIZATION_HEADER_PREFIX + cmsRestApiCreds);
        HttpEntity<AbstractActorDTO> postRequest = new HttpEntity<>(actor, headers);
        ResponseEntity<String> postResponse = restTemplate.exchange(cmsRestApiUrl+"/actors", HttpMethod.POST,
                postRequest, String.class);
    }
```

And I am calling this function like this:

```
PersonActorDTO actor = new PersonActorDTO();
createActorInstance(actor);
```

Mention that AbstractActorDTO class is superclass for PersonActorDTO.

Abstract DTO:

```
public abstract class AbstractActorDTO extends AbstractDTO {
    @DTOProperty(
        entityProperty = "actorInstance.actor.actorCategory"
    )
    private String actorCategoryID;
    @DTOProperty(
        entityProperty = "actorInstance.scope"
    )
    private String scopeID;

    public AbstractActorDTO() {
    }

    public String getActorCategoryID() {
        return this.actorCategoryID;
    }

    public void setActorCategoryID(String actorCategoryID) {
        this.actorCategoryID = actorCategoryID;
    }

    public String getScopeID() {
        return this.scopeID;
    }

    public void setScopeID(String scopeID) {
        this.scopeID = scopeID;
    }
}
```

PersonActorDTO:

```
public class PersonActorDTO extends AbstractActorCreateDTO {
    @DTOProperty(
        entityProperty = "actorInstance.aliases"
    )
    private List<PersonAliasDTO> aliases = new ArrayList();
    @DTOProperty
    private String firstName;
    @DTOProperty
    private String middleName;
    @DTOProperty
    private String lastName;
    @DTOProperty
    private String prefix;
    @DTOProperty
    private String suffix;

    public PersonActorDTO() {
    }

    public List<PersonAliasDTO> getAliases() {
        return this.aliases;
    }

    public void setAliases(List<PersonAliasDTO> aliases) {
        this.aliases = aliases;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
        return this.firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getMiddleName() {
        return this.middleName;
    }

    public void setMiddleName(String middleName) {
        this.middleName = middleName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return this.lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public String getPrefix() {
        return this.prefix;
    }

    public void setPrefix(String prefix) {
        this.prefix = prefix;
    }

    public String getSuffix() {
        return this.suffix;
    }

    public void setSuffix(String suffix) {
        this.suffix = suffix;
    }
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Could you post the content of your DTO objects (both the abstract superclass and its implementation)? Also, could you state which version of Spring you are using. The most recent ones have the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter automatically added to the list of message converters of the RestTemplate, but older ones might not and you might have to register the converter by yourself.

Comment: @deepdownunder2222 done